# Calculating the similarity between three 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

My data consists of lots of 3D numpy arrays that represent a 3D greyscale volume. These volumes can be imported into a numpy array. This is the only way I have of importing them into python in general as they are a weird file format.

I have a reference 3D volume with an object at its centre and then lots and lots of other 3D volumes some of which should contain the object at the centre in a certain orientation (a cylinder). The data is incredibly noisy. The reference volume has a much high SNR than the other volumes but all are noisy.

To calculate the likelihood that the 3D volumes contain the cylinder in the same place and orientation as the reference volume I have come up with the current system.

1. I project the reference volume down the 0 axis.
2. I project the reference volume down the 1 axis
3. I project the other volumes down the 0 axis
4. I project a numpy array full of noise down the 0 axis (the axis doesn't matter for this one)

I then compare 1 to 3, 2 to 3 and 3 to 4.

Currently I have tried doing the mean squared error and generally the crosscorrelation coefficient. Neither have been successful. What other ways are there to compare there images?